# draw arrow on arc with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a arrow head on a arch but the size sounds like too bit and direction not correct!

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=50x50,outfile=\jobname.gif}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,>=triangle 60]
\def\r{0.35}
\draw[draw=black] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
%\draw (0,0) circle (\r);
\centerarc[->,line cap=round](0,0)(330:30:\r)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know the size is too small! I wish to use it as a icon.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many reasons why the `arrows` library is said to be superseded by `arrows.meta`, this is one of them. The IMHO most elegant way to add such a big arrow to this tiny arc is to bend it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=50x50,outfile=\jobname.gif}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+(#3:#5)$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,>={Triangle[bend]}]
\def\r{0.35}
\draw[draw=black] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
%\draw (0,0) circle (\r);
\centerarc[->,line cap=round](0,0)(330:30:\r)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I were to make this an icon, I probably would use a slightly smaller arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=50x50,outfile=\jobname.gif}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+(#3:#5)$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,>={Triangle[bend,length=10pt,width=10pt]}]
\def\r{0.35}
\draw[draw=black] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
%\draw (0,0) circle (\r);
\centerarc[->,line cap=round](0,0)(330:30:\r)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Customize arrow tip maybe workaround this issue but need manually adjust the yoffset and rotation angle case by case!

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=50x50,outfile=\jobname.gif}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5) {\draw[#1] (#2)++(#3:#5) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
 \pgfarrowsdeclare{myarr}{myarr}% My arrow tip
 { \pgfarrowsleftextend{-2\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{2\pgflinewidth}}
 {\pgftransformrotate{-40}%angle
  %\pgftransformxshift{1\pgflinewidth}
 \pgftransformyshift{\pgflinewidth} 
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2\pgflinewidth}{0\pgflinewidth}} %A
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0\pgflinewidth}{1.5\pgflinewidth}} %B
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0\pgflinewidth}{-1.5\pgflinewidth}} %C
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,>=myarr]
\def\r{0.35}
\draw[draw=black] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\centerarc[->,line cap=round](0,0)(330:30:\r)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]